# I have a data of temperatures for each month of a hundred years. How do I calculate the average of the temperatures for each year?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this is a noob question, apologies for that. But I have a list of data in the following format:

```
{
    "Year": 1881,
    "Jan": -8,
    "Feb": -13,
    "Mar": 2,
    "Apr": -2,
    "May": -3,
    "Jun": -27,
    "Jul": -5,
    "Aug": -1,
    "Sep": -8,
    "Oct": -18,
    "Nov": -25,
    "Dec": -14,
    "J-D": -10,
    "D-N": -11,
    "DJF": -13,
    "MAM": -1,
    "JJA": -11,
    "SON": -17
},
{
    "Year": 1882,
    "Jan": 10,
    "Feb": 10,
    "Mar": 2,
    "Apr": -19,
    "May": -17,
    "Jun": -24,
    "Jul": -9,
    "Aug": 5,
    "Sep": 0,
    "Oct": -21,
    "Nov": -20,
    "Dec": -24,
    "J-D": -9,
    "D-N": -8,
    "DJF": 2,
    "MAM": -11,
    "JJA": -9,
    "SON": -14
},
```

etc.

I want to calculate the average of the temperatures for each year. There are over 100 years. What is the easiest way to do this? Putting them in arrays, and manually calculating them would take too long. Even then I don't know how to assign the average temperature to each year. What way can I write this code? I am working with Javascript.

Comment: add all the temperatures for each month in a year and divide by 12 - that's how averages are calculated

Comment: Thanks, but there are a lot of years.

Comment: @studious—you have to iterate to get the temps, so implement that so you get the correct result. Only then if you have performance issues look to fix them. 100 years worth shouldn't take very long.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance here. 100 years is not that much. Computers are fast

Comment: OK, so you know how averages are done - I guess the problem is that you don't know how to write javascript - I wasn't sure from the question if you had no idea about maths or javascript

Comment: I take it you want a more precise average than the one that already exists in the data?  Your "J-D" parameter appears to be the Jan-Dec average rounded to the nearest integer. If you do want a more precise average than rounded to an integer, you should consider adjusting each month's contribution to the yearly average to be proportional to the number of days in the month.

Comment: @Makyen great catch, I totally missed the "J-D" property :)

Comment: @Phil, Thanks. The other fields also appear to be averages but over a few months (e.g. "MAM"=March-May; "JJA"=Jun-Aug; "SON"=Sept-Nov). Some didn't match my expectations until I realized they were averages that included months in the prior year (e.g. "D-N"=previous Dec through current Nov; "DJF"=previous Dec through current February).

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll need an array of keys to represent the months (so you can ignore all the other data)

```
let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ...];
```

Then, assuming your data is in an actual array, you can use a [reduce operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (well, two reduce operations) to produce a map of year to average

```js
let years = [{"Year":1881,"Jan":-8,"Feb":-13,"Mar":2,"Apr":-2,"May":-3,"Jun":-27,"Jul":-5,"Aug":-1,"Sep":-8,"Oct":-18,"Nov":-25,"Dec":-14,"J-D":-10,"D-N":-11,"DJF":-13,"MAM":-1,"JJA":-11,"SON":-17},{"Year":1882,"Jan":10,"Feb":10,"Mar":2,"Apr":-19,"May":-17,"Jun":-24,"Jul":-9,"Aug":5,"Sep":0,"Oct":-21,"Nov":-20,"Dec":-24,"J-D":-9,"D-N":-8,"DJF":2,"MAM":-11,"JJA":-9,"SON":-14}];

let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

let averages = years.reduce((avgs, year) => {
    let sum = months.reduce((avg, month) => avg + year[month], 0);
    avgs[year.Year] = sum / months.length;
    return avgs;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(averages, null, '  ') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: That's almost identical to what I came up with. Far better to post as a runnable snippet here than elsewhere.

Comment: @RobG I just hate putting the initial data in the runnable snippets

Comment: @RobG done. Wish there was a hidden "initial data" section in the snippet editor

Comment: Yep, maybe one for the suggestion box. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using modern Array methods, which make the solution easier to read by taking the problem and breaking it down into steps.

```
// The data you provided
var data = [
    {
        "Year": 1881,
        "Jan": -8,
        "Feb": -13,
        "Mar": 2,
        "Apr": -2,
        "May": -3,
        "Jun": -27,
        "Jul": -5,
        "Aug": -1,
        "Sep": -8,
        "Oct": -18,
        "Nov": -25,
        "Dec": -14,
        "J-D": -10,
        "D-N": -11,
        "DJF": -13,
        "MAM": -1,
        "JJA": -11,
        "SON": -17
    },
    {
        "Year": 1882,
        "Jan": 10,
        "Feb": 10,
        "Mar": 2,
        "Apr": -19,
        "May": -17,
        "Jun": -24,
        "Jul": -9,
        "Aug": 5,
        "Sep": 0,
        "Oct": -21,
        "Nov": -20,
        "Dec": -24,
        "J-D": -9,
        "D-N": -8,
        "DJF": 2,
        "MAM": -11,
        "JJA": -9,
        "SON": -14
    },
];

// Hardcode which keys count towards the average, ignore the rest like "Year"
// and "J-D".
var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');

var result = data.map(yearData => ({     // Set `result` to `data` with each
                                         // item replaced with an object with...
    Year: yearData.Year,                 // The `Year` property copied
    average: (months                     // An `average` property set to the
                                         // result of taking `months` and...
        .map(month => yearData[month])   // Replacing each item with the value
                                         // at that key in the current year data
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b)         // Then taking the sum of the Array
        / months.length                  // Then going from sum to average by
                                         // dividing by the number of items
    ),
}));

// `result` now contains the averages.
```

There are a lot of ways to approach the problem, this isn't the only solution. What every approach will have in common is that, one way or another, you need to iterate over the Array (done by `map` and `reduce` here), store the sum as you do (here handled implicitly by `reduce`), then divide by the number of months.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s9oe7ddp/)

```js
var temps = [
{ "Year": 1881, "Jan": -8, "Feb": -13, "Mar": 2, "Apr": -2, "May": -3, "Jun": -27, "Jul": -5, "Aug": -1, "Sep": -8, "Oct": -18, "Nov": -25, "Dec": -14, "J-D": -10, "D-N": -11, "DJF": -13, "MAM": -1, "JJA": -11, "SON": -17 },
{ "Year": 1882, "Jan": 10, "Feb": 10, "Mar": 2, "Apr": -19, "May": -17, "Jun": -24, "Jul": -9, "Aug": 5, "Sep": 0, "Oct": -21, "Nov": -20, "Dec": -24, "J-D": -9, "D-N": -8, "DJF": 2, "MAM": -11, "JJA": -9, "SON": -14 }
],
total = 0;

for(var i=0, lng = temps.length; i < lng; ++i){
    var y = temps[i],
   yearAvg = parseFloat(((y.Jan + y.Feb + y.Mar + y.Apr + y.May + y.Jun + y.Jul + y.Aug + y.Sep + y.Oct + y.Nov + y.Dec ) / 12).toFixed(2), 10);
    console.log(y.Year + ' average = ' + yearAvg);
  total += yearAvg;
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Total Avergae: ' + total/temps.length;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest writing a python script to parse the string into a multi dimensional dictionary. The first layer of the dict should be keys representing the years and the values should hold the second layer dictionary where the keys are the months of the year and the values are the associated temperatures. From there you can write a function to iterate through the dict and calculate the averages as Jaromanda suggested.

I'd write it out for you but this is a good project to learn with. Look up python multi dimensional dictionaries and how to parse strings.

Comment: Why are you offering a Python solution to a question tagged JavaScript?

Comment: I'm offering what I think would be a good solution to the problem he is having. Considering the fact that he is new to writing code, I think it would make sense to use python as it isn't to difficult to learn and make it do what you want. Beyond that, Python is a great language for back end when it comes to web development and an awesome way to get started with coding in general. Javascript is primarily for web development as apposed to basic number crunching, in addition, it is a tricky language in comparison to python when you have little to no experience.